# Word that "sounds" like its meaning, not onomatopoeia (ex. twinkle)

Tags: single-word-requests

What I am looking for is a word that describes words that are read with a sound representative of their connotation. To my understanding this would differ from an onomatopoeia in that onomatopoeia's deal with the denotation of a word. This is hard for me to explain (also hard to google) so I am going to give some examples:

- Twinkle
- Sludge
- Bell
- Splash (this might just be an onomatopoeia)

These words sound like the things they mean when spoken *without* explicitly meaning their sound.

Contrast this to onomatopoeias whos meaning is only their sound:

- Bang
- Boom
- Tic

I am convinced that at some point I knew the answer to this question but I have since forgotten it.

Since I have tagged this as a single-word request here is a sample sentence:

> "The word Twinkle is a ------- because it sounds sparkly and light when spoken which is appropriate to its meaning, but not directly connected"

Thanks in advance for the help, let me know if I can clarify this at all!

Comment: It's absolutely subjective. To me, *twinkie* sounds hard and heavy.

Comment: You sometimes see it listed as [imitative](https://www.google.com/search?q=clang+etymology&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=clang+etymology&aqs=chrome..69i57.7291j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean because twinkle is a verb; sludge and bell are nouns. I don't think you can say that twinkle sounds sparkly. It doesn't have any sound at all....and bang, boom and tic are not necessarily onomatopoeic words, either.

Comment: @Lambie while I agree this is subjective I don't think that is contrary to the point? Even if you disagree about the sound, I am still looking for a word to describe the effect.

Comment: I just don't understand it. I can't understand what you are looking for. I am not criticizing anything at all.

Comment: Here's the complete set of [simplex words with `TW-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/tw.pdf). As you can see, it's 100% coherent, which means all the words are associated with one or more semantic loci.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. My example would be a British word like doolally. Somehow it's meaning sounds right for the sound of the word.

Comment: Ken, the question is asking for a word that covers words that sound like their meaning. You have given an example of such a word, but not what was sought, which was a word for that class of words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you could say that these words are ***phon(a)esthemic***.<sup>1</sup> Several<sup>2</sup> of the words you are describing feature a [*phon(a)estheme*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phonestheme)<sup>3</sup> which contributes to your sense that their meaning is somehow reflected in their sound. From Merriam-Webster:

> **Definition of phonestheme**
>   *linguistics*
>
> the common feature of sound occurring in a group of symbolic words
>
> - *He points to a 1929 experiment by Edward Sapir in which Sapir's subjects were asked to match nonsense words with small and large versions of the same object. The subjects tended to match words with a high vowel (such as ee) to the small object and those with a low vowel (such as the o in "cot") to the larger object. British linguist J.R. Firth later called these links between sound and meaning "phonesthemes."* —Michael Erard

A [ThoughtCo article by Richard Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/phonestheme-word-sounds-1691505) offers a more straightforward definition:

> A *phonestheme* is a particular sound or sound sequence that (at least in a general way) suggests a certain meaning. The adjective form is *phonesthemic*.

So you could say

> "The word Twinkle is **phon(a)esthemic** because [it contains sounds that are associated with sudden or repetitive motion and smallness, so it] sounds sparkly and light when spoken which is appropriate to its meaning, but not directly connected"

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>For those who still aren't sure about this phenomenon, Terry Pratchett explains it better than I can (though it seems he wasn't aware of any common word for it):</sub>

> <sub>Glint, glisten, glitter, gleam...</sub>
>
> <sub>Tiffany thought a lot about words, in the long hours of churning butter. 'Onomatopoeic', she'd discovered in the dictionary, meant words that sounded like the noise of the thing they were describing, like 'cuckoo'. But *she* thought there should be a word meaning 'a word that sounds like the noise a thing would make if that thing made a noise even though, actually, it doesn't, but would if it did.'</sub>
>
> <sub>*Glint*, for example. If light made a noise as it reflected off a distant window, it'd go 'glint!' And the light of tinsel, all those little glints chiming together, would make a noise like 'glitterglitter'. 'Gleam' was a clean, smooth noise from a surface that intended to shine all day. And 'glisten' was the soft, almost greasy sound of something rich and oily.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>[Wikipedia includes *sludge* in its examples of phonesthemic words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme#Examples) (*sl*- words are one of the classic English phonestheme examples, along with *gl*-; *sl*- words are often pejorative and/or slippery, and *sludge* fits both), and *twinkle* also appears on some lists (both for the [*tw*-](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/tw.pdf) start and [-*le*](http://www.academia.edu/35540474/Morphology_and_Syntax_Phonesthemes_and_Difficulties_in_Morphemic_Analysis) end). *Splash* does have onomatopoeic features, but it also appears on lists with other liquidy [*spl*-](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/spl.pdf) words like *splat* and *splutter*. I'm not sure whether *bell* contains any phonesthemic features.</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>These sounds are also sometimes called [*sub-morphemes*](https://journals.openedition.org/lexis/688) (because they seem to carry some meaning even though they don't reach the level of a morpheme) or [*word-affinities*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/452731). They are related to [*ideophones*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone) and fall under the more general heading of [sound symbolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism)/phon(a)esthesia/phonosemantics, an area of expertise for EL&U's own [John Lawler](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/). There seems to be a continuing debate about whether the "meaning" that attaches to the various sounds is always language-specific (some dictionaries specifically define the phenomenon as a *result* of having a large number of related words in a language that share the sound) or if there is some inherent, universal connection between some of the sounds and human perception of their connotations, but either way I believe this describes the experience described in the question.</sub>

Comment: Please mention that this word is also commonly spelled [*phonaestheme*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/142612?redirectedFrom=phonaestheme#eid) for aesthetic reasons. :)

Comment: @tchrist Is that enough?

Comment: Thanks. The OED text for the word reads: “A phoneme or group of phonemes having recognizable semantic associations, as a result of appearing in a number of words of similar meaning.”

Comment: I looked at that definition, and some others that are very similar, but I feel like there's enough scholarly debate about causality that I wanted to stay away from that second clause (it might be right, but it isn't clear to me that everyone who uses the term would agree with it).

Comment: In *Letters* 176, Tolkien mentions how he took ‘phonaesthetic pleasure’ in inventing his own names and verse in his created languages.

Comment: Accepting this answer 'phonestheme' seems like a usable word to describe these words even though it specifically refers to the sounds and not the whole words. Lots of additional useful information provided. thanks

Answer (score 6):

The area of linguistics that studies these associations is called

> [phonosemantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism).

de Saussure was the first to really explicitly remark on the arbitrariness of the connection between sound and meaning. And this arbitrariness is a hallmark of language. But language is so large that there is room enough for some very small piece of non-arbitrariness (?). In many languages there are sound clusters that are not full words or even affixes, but they still appear in a number of words giving those words some vague common meaning.

For example

> glitter, gleam, glow,

all have something to do with light.

This is related to the

> [Bouba-kiki effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect)

where across many very unrelated languages, there seems to be an association with particular sounds common to those languages and non-linguistic shapes. For example, experimentally it has been shown that the nonsense word 'bouba' is more often associated with a smooth round object and 'kiki' with a spiky object.

Comment: I think what is arbitrary with Saussure are signs.

Comment: According to Douglas Harper's Online Etymology Dictionary, the words "glitter", "gleam" and "glow" all derive from a common Proto-Indo-European root meaning "to shine", so that explains the similarity there. (The family contains *lots* of words, actually, including: glare, glass, glimmer, glimpse, glint, glisten, gloss, gold.)

Comment: This is some really cool information that I will check out. I think you make a good point of cross-language application. I am not going to accept this answer for now because I am still hoping for a one word answer. Cheers

Comment: Here's the [analysis for simplex `GL-` words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gl.pdf).  Etymology, however, is a weak reed to lean on, as [the case of _Style_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf) shows. More information about phonosemantic research can be found on [my web page](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/#mono).

Comment: @BenjaminShaffer Hmm, "phonosemantics" *is* a one-word answer.

Comment: @Lawrence OP was asking for a single word describing the words involved. "Phonosemantics" refers to the phenomenon and its study, not the words themselves.

Comment: @RozennKeribin Good point. In that case, I think *onomatopoeia* is still serviceable. It might not be a word that sounds like a sound, but these are words that sound like the concepts they represent.

Comment: @Lawrence at least having a word to describe them is good but as Rozenn said it isn't exactly the form I was hoping for. Maybe there is some form of "phonosemantic" like "phonosemant" haha

Comment: @Oosaka Fora single word for these common sound sequences, I think the operative term would be 'cognate'.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to leave a comment saying I got what you were saying, and also felt I'd run into a word for this but couldn't think of it either (I wouldn't leave such a comment normally except that so many others were disagreeing with the very premise of your question). Then what do you know, the Wikipedia page for "Phonosemantics" has this among the "See also" links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone

I'm not 100% certain it's the word I was thinking of but it could be. It seems to apply to clusters of sounds, not just words, and a lot of their examples are basically onomatopoeia, but they literally include the English verb "twinkle" as an example.

Comment: Ideophones are systemic phenomena that have a number of characteristics that English assonance-rime phonosemantic phenomena don't.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Your note about ideophones in [another answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/27598/) is ambiguous ("often associated with", "strictly speaking not"), summing up in the end, that ""Ideophone" is not a well-defined term". Wiktionary attributes the term to a certain treatment of the Yoruba language; That hardly compares to English. However the surface analysis *ide-*+*phone*, and the definition in WT do fit what we mean with Onomatopoea. In effect, I think all words express *ideas* and are *phonetic*, so it's a leaky abstraction. Maybe the original coinage was imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe autological?

"An autological word is a word that expresses a property that it also possesses. The opposite is a heterological word, one that does not apply to itself. It is not to be confused with autonym, which means one's own name, or a name by which a people or ethnic group refers to itself." -wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

The word **echoism** is sometimes used as the noun form of **echoic**.

*Oxford English Dictionary* gives this definition of **echoic**:

> Of the nature of an echo: a term proposed by J. A. H. Murray and used in this Dictionary to describe formations which echo the sound which they are intended to denote or symbolize.

**Having said that**, it is worth noting that there is not really a strong distinction between **echoic** and **onomatopoeic.**  The latter word is cross-referenced to **echoic** in the *OED*, and **echoism** is a rare term.

Here is an example of the *OED* using "echoic" to describe the origin of the word **clock**, which meant "bell" before it meant the thing that tells time.

> Wherever it actually arose, it was probably **echoic**, imitating the rattling made by the early handbells of sheet-iron and quadrilateral shape, rather than the ringing of the cast circular bell of later date. The relation of the rare Old English *cluc(c)ge* to the other forms, which agree generally with the types *klok , klokka* , is obscure.

In this sense, "echoic" might be said to have some relevant distinction from the term onomatopoeia in that a word can have an echoic origin without being termed an onomatopoeia itself, like the word "clock," or, likely, "bell."

The origin of "sludge" appears to be unknown, and "twinkle" is traced to Old English *twinclian*.  Other senses of the word "twinkle" that refer to sound are described as echoic.

Comment: Interesting but ultimately felt the accepted answer is closer to what I was looking for. An important distinction is that echoic words explicitly originated from the sounds (to my understanding) whereas the phonestheme describes the sound independent of it's origin. Thanks for the answer :)